# I'm learning x86 assembly on OS X 10.6, how do I compile?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm about to learn x86 assembly language on Mac OS X.
I'm using as instruction to compile assembly file in commend window. 
But I have several errors and I don't know how I can get through.

Here are the errors and my assembly code, which is quite simple.

```
**ung-mi-lims-macbook-pro:pa2 ungmi$ as swap.s
swap.s:16:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
swap.s:16:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 115 (s).
swap.s:19:suffix or operands invalid for `push'
swap.s:46:suffix or operands invalid for `pop'
ung-mi-lims-macbook-pro:pa2 ungmi$**
```

and the source is

```
.text
        .align 4
.globl  swap
        .type swap,@function

swap:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp

        movl    %ebp, %esp
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

and I searched some solution which is I have to put -arch i386 than

```
**ung-mi-lims-macbook-pro:pa2 ungmi$ as -arch i386 swap.s
swap.s:16:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
swap.s:16:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 115 (s).
ung-mi-lims-macbook-pro:pa2 ungmi$**
```

Could you help me out?  Just let me know what I need to compile assembly file.
I have XCode already and I'd rather to do this with commend window and vi editor.

Comment: Not sure, but gcc uses something like  `.def swap; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef` after the line `.globl swap` to denote functions.

Comment: @susmits Not on OS X 10.5 Intel, and I assume not on 10.6 either. As KennyTM points out that seems to depend very much on the binary format of the platform for which compilation is happening.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 6):

Your code is 32-bit assembly. Compilation on Snow Leopard is 64-bit by default, but you can use `gcc -m32` for compiling 32-bit code. There are of course also options that you can pass to `as` and `ld` but I found that remembering only the option for `gcc` was enough, since it is a front-end to all these things.

Use gcc to show you an example of assembly code that works: type a minimal C function in file test.c and use `gcc -S test.c` to produce the assembly in file test.s.

Example:

```
int x;

void f(void)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)  x = x + 1;
}
```

is compiled in assembly on this Leopard Mac:

```
    .text
.globl _f
_f:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    call    L6
"L00000000001$pb":
L6:
    popl    %ecx
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    jmp L2
L3:
    leal    L_x$non_lazy_ptr-"L00000000001$pb"(%ecx), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    leal    1(%eax), %edx
    leal    L_x$non_lazy_ptr-"L00000000001$pb"(%ecx), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    %edx, (%eax)
    leal    -12(%ebp), %eax
    incl    (%eax)
L2:
    cmpl    $4, -12(%ebp)
    jle L3
    leave
    ret
.comm _x,4,2
    .section __IMPORT,__pointers,non_lazy_symbol_pointers
L_x$non_lazy_ptr:
    .indirect_symbol _x
    .long   0
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

You can make it simpler by using gcc option -fno-PIC:

```
    .text
.globl _f
_f:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
    jmp L2
L3:
    movl    _x, %eax
    incl    %eax
    movl    %eax, _x
    leal    -12(%ebp), %eax
    incl    (%eax)
L2:
    cmpl    $4, -12(%ebp)
    jle L3
    leave
    ret
.comm _x,4,2
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

On Snow Leopard you will get 64-bit assembly (amd64). You could get the same thing on Leopard by using the -m64 gcc option, and you can get on Snow Leopard the same thing you'd get running gcc on Leopard with the -m32 option.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.4/gcc/), it'll compile and link for you: `cc swap.s`

Answer (score 2):

Apple's `as` is forked from binutils 1.38, while the current version is 2.20, so there may be many new directives not available. I can't find the manual for 1.38, but the [oldest one (2.10) I could find](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.10/as_7.html#SEC143) states that `.type` is associated only with COFF format output. The object format on Mac is Mach-O, so the `.type` directive is meaningless. Just remove it.

Comment: thank you so much.. but they have other errors.. actually professor ask us to install linux.. but I thought..mac os is similar to linux because both are based on unix.. :( errors are 

ung-mi-lims-macbook-pro:pa2 ungmi$ gcc -m32 swap.s
Undefined symbols:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @kevin: You need to have a `main` to start the program. You'd better install Linux.

Comment: ya.. thank you so much~~ but finally I've just installed ubuntu on my laptop.. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have ran in to this issue as well trying to compile Intel x86 on Mac OS X:

#### For nasm:

```
-o hello.tmp - outfile
-f macho - specify format
Linux - elf or elf64
Mac OSX - macho
```

#### For ld:

```
-arch i386 - specify architecture (32 bit assembly)
-macosx_version_min 10.6 (Mac OSX - complains about default specification)
-no_pie (Mac OSX - removes ld warning)
-e main - specify main symbol name (Mac OSX - default is start)
-o hello.o - outfile
```

#### For Shell:

```
./hello.o - execution
```

#### One-liner:

```
nasm -o hello.tmp -f macho hello.s && ld -arch i386 -macosx_version_min 10.6 -no_pie -e _main -o hello.o hello.tmp && ./hello.o
```

Let me know if this helps!

I wrote how to do it on my blog here:

http://blog.burrowsapps.com/2013/07/how-to-compile-helloworld-in-intel-x86.html

For a more verbose explanation, I explained on my Github here:

https://github.com/jaredsburrows/Assembly