# Compiling ELF like assembly on OS X Yosemite

Tags: gcc, assembly, compilation, osx-yosemite

In the context of a compiler construction project, I used to be able to compile "ia32" code like this before:

```
$ gcc -m32 -ofoo foo.s
```

with foo.s looking like:

```
        .file   "tiger-runtime.c"
        .text
        .globl  tc_init_array
        .type   tc_init_array, @function
tc_init_array:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushl   %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        .cfi_offset 5, -8
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
        subl    $40, %esp
        movl    8(%ebp), %eax
        sall    $2, %eax
        movl    %eax, (%esp)
        call    malloc
        movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
        movl    $0, -12(%ebp)
        jmp     .L2
```

Now that I moved to Yosemite and the latest version of Xcode, I get:

```
$ gcc-mp-5 -m32 -oadd-ia32 add-ia32.s   
tiger-runtime.c:4:Unknown pseudo-op: .type
tiger-runtime.c:4:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 116 (t).
tiger-runtime.c:7:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_startproc
tiger-runtime.c:9:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_def_cfa_offset
tiger-runtime.c:9:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 56 (8).
tiger-runtime.c:10:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_offset
tiger-runtime.c:10:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 53 (5).
tiger-runtime.c:12:Unknown pseudo-op: .cfi_def_cfa_register
```

and more errors like this.  This question has been asked many times, but none of the answers I've seen so far work on Yosemite (e.g., [mac OSX Unknown pseudo-op: .type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22269223/mac-osx-unknown-pseudo-op-type), [I'm learning x86 assembly on OS X 10.6, how do I compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752570/im-learning-x86-assembly-on-os-x-10-6-how-do-i-compile)).  In particular, even if I use GCC (say GCC 5 via MacPorts) as a compiler driver, it appears to use `/usr/bin/as`, not its own assembler.

I have installed several versions of GCC/Clang/Binutils (via MacPorts) to try to find the right assembly, but without success.  At best, I get:

```
$ /opt/local/i386-elf/bin/as add-ia32.s -o add-ia32.o
$ /opt/local/i386-elf/bin/ld add-ia32.o -o add-ia32
/opt/local/i386-elf/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000
add-ia32.o: In function `tc_init_array':
tiger-runtime.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `malloc'
add-ia32.o: In function `tc_malloc':
tiger-runtime.c:(.text+0x54): undefined reference to `malloc'
tiger-runtime.c:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `stderr'
tiger-runtime.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `fwrite'
tiger-runtime.c:(.text+0x94): undefined reference to `exit'
```

I guess I'm not too far from completion, yet the convention for the main function seems to differ, and it doesn't find the libc (`-lc` does not help).

A full version of the assembly file that used to work properly is available here: http://pastebin.com/Xq8DTmf6.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need `gas`, perhaps?

Comment: Gas does not appear to be available from MacPorts.  Actually, that's why I tried to install the binutils, to get gas, and I guess I did get gas (`/opt/local/i386-elf/bin/as`).  Yet that does not suffice.

Comment: You might need a leading underscore on symbol names.

Comment: @Jester No, I get the same result with `_malloc` etc.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between assembly on mac and assembly on linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720084/what-is-the-difference-between-assembly-on-mac-and-assembly-on-linux)